# reactjs file structure clarification

Tags: reactjs

I'm fairly new to reactJS and looking for some clarification.  I have a fairly simple reactJS application with several components and a utility javascript file containing functions I would like to be able to call from each component.

My util.js file looks something like this:

```
export function printMe(txtToPrint){
     console.log(txtToPrint);
}
export function addUs(a,b){
     return a + b;
}
```

my ComponentA looks something like this:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import  {printMe, addUs} from './util';
...
```

and my folder structure looks like:

```
/src
/src/components/componentA/componentA.js
/src/util.js
```

when I run the application, I receive an error stating:

```
Module not found: './util' 'src/components/componentsA'
```

However, when I change the import statements on the componentA to look like this:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import  {printMe, addUs} from '../../util';
```

Everything works.  I am/was under the impression ./ is location of src. Is it not the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The urls are relative to the file where they are declared.

If you're inside componentA.js:

`./` is inside the componentA folder,

`../` is inside the components folder,

`../../` is inside the src folder. That's why this one works

Check this for more info: https://webpack.github.io/docs/resolving.html#resolving-a-relative-path